# Разница между print и return при возврате значения из функции

Tags: python, python-3.x

Прохожу обучалку на codeacademy по python. 
задание - написать функцию, которая суммирует цифры числа и возвращает результат сложения.
мой код:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    n = str(n)
    summ = 0
    for i in n:
        summ += int(i)
    print summ

digit_sum(234)
```

результат: 9
но выскакивает ошибка, мол по заданию я должнен вернуть (`return`) сумму.

изменяю код:

```
def digit_sum(n):
    n = str(n)
    summ = 0
    for i in n:
        summ += int(i)
    return summ

digit_sum(234)
print summ
```

появляется сообщение, что задание выполнено верно но результат почему-то 15... при чем, результат 15 независимо от того какой аргумент функции я задал (будь то 234, 32145 или 111) 
не могу понять в чем проблема...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не сохраняете значение, которое возвращает `digit_sum(234)`

В конце нужно написать:

```
print digit_sum(234)
```

Или:

```
a = digit_sum(234)
print a
```

Переменная `summ` является локальной переменной функции `digit_sum(n)` и к ней нельзя получить доступ снаружи таким образом.

Comment: точно. спасибо большое за оперативный ответ! :) но все равно не могу понять откуда берется ответ 15.

Comment: Я думаю, 15 это какая-то внутренняя переменная интерпретатора на codeacademy, если выполнить этот код в системе, получится `NameError: name 'summ' is not defined`

Comment: понял. еще раз спасибо!