# Найти индекс элемента в списке, иначе вернуть -1

Tags: python

Надо на Python заделать вот это:

Функция `find(arr, value)`, которая ищет в массиве `arr` значение `value` и возвращает его номер в массиве. Иначе возвращает `-1`.

Comment: Что у вас получилось до сих пор?

Comment: `arr = [56, 89, 88, 23, 15]
num = int(input("Enter a number"))
def find(arr, value):
    for value in arr:
        print(arr.index(value))
    else:
        print("-1")
`

Comment: Пожалуйста, кнопкой [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/758929/edit) добавте в вопрос, потом можете удалить комментарий.

Comment: связанный вопрос [Разница между print и return при возврате значения из функции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/618734/23044)

Answer (score 4):

```
def find(arr, val):
  try:
    return arr.index(val)
  except ValueError:
    return -1
```

[**demo**](https://eval.in/920010)

Answer (score 0):

```
In [4]: def find(array, value, index=0):
   ...:     if index >= len(array):
   ...:         return -1
   ...:     elif array[index] == value:
   ...:         return index
   ...:     return find(array, value, index + 1)
   ...:

In [5]: find([1, 2, 3], 4)
Out[5]: -1

In [6]: find([1, 2, 3], 3)
Out[6]: 2
```

Или:

```
In [8]: def find(array, value):
   ...:     if value in array:
   ...:         return array.index(value)
   ...:     return -1
   ...:

In [9]: find([1, 2, 3, 'lol'], 'lol')
Out[9]: 3
```

Либо вариант покороче:

```
In [16]: find = lambda array, value: array.index(value) if value in array else -1
```

Answer (score -2):

Самое простое линейный поиск:

```
def search(lst, val):
    for i in range(lst):
        if lst[i] == val:
            return i
    return -1
```